# Why umask in C program doen't work as expected

Tags: permissions, umask

I have the following code comes from the apue book:

```
#define RWRWRW (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH)

int
main()
{
    umask(0);
    if(creat("foo",RWRWRW)<0)
        err_sys("creat error for foo");
    umask(S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
    if(creat("bar",RWRWRW)<0)
        err_sys("create error for bar");
    exit(0);
}
```

In `terminal`, I first all `umask` to get the current mode creation :
 I get 0002.
Then run this program. I get the following :

```
$ ls -l foo bar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 May 15 14:28 bar
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 May 15 14:28 foo
```

But it should be like this :

```
$ ls -l foo bar
-rw------- 1 sar 0 Dec 7 21:20 bar 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sar 0 Dec 7 21:20 foo
```

So what's going on? Why the umask in my program doesn't work?

Comment: Are the files on an NTFS/FAT32 file system?

Comment: I run it in WSL of windows and also in Fedora in VMware. Both get this result.@muru

Comment: Fedora is off-topic here, and the question about the filesystem still applies.

Comment: Oh I get the right result. It is the problem of the file system. Maybe the problem comes to the shared folder interface with VMware. When I move the code into another folder, both the Ubuntu and Fedora works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sut whe"re did you move it to? an EXT4 partition?

Comment: @Febby , I just move the file from the shared folder to Document folder, and yes it's an EXT4 partition.